# How to exclude rows in sql server insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a statement like this

```
insert into A (id, nid)
(
    select id, 100 as nid
    from B
    group by id
)
```

this works, but the problem is table A, has a primary key constraint on (id, nid), and some of the rows in the computed nested query, already exist in table A. How can I exclude them from being included in the nested query?

Thanks

Comment: use the merge statement and ignore the matches

Answer (score 4):

You could use `EXCEPT`:

```
insert into A (id, nid)
select id, 100 as nid
from B
group by id
EXCEPT
SELECT id, nid
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the rows exist...

```
insert into A (id, nid)
select id, 100 as nid
from B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id = B.id AND A.nid = 100)
group by id
```

PS: the parenthesis around your select are unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Add Where clause:

```
insert A (id, nid)
select id, 100 as nid
from B
Where Not exists (Select * from A 
                  Where id = B.Id
                    and nid = 100)
group by id
```